# SimilarityRules for SequenceAlignment of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, sequence, alignment

I am trying to use the `SimilarityRules` option of `SequenceAlignment` to customize its output. This works perfectly for strings, but I cannot get it to work for lists.

Compare the following outputs:

```
SequenceAlignment["abcba","abdcba"]
```

> ```
> {"ab", {"", "d"}, "cba"}
> ```

```
SequenceAlignment[{a, b, c, b, a}, {a, b, d, c, b, a}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b}, {{}, {d}}, {c, b, a}}
> ```

```
SequenceAlignment["abcba", "abdcba", 
  SimilarityRules -> {{a_, a_} -> 1, {a_, b_} -> -1}]
```

> ```
> {"ab", {"", "d"}, "cba"}
> ```

```
SequenceAlignment[{a, b, c, b, a}, {a, b, d, c, b, a}, 
  SimilarityRules -> {{a_, a_} -> 1, {a_, b_} -> -1}]
```

> ```
> SequenceAlignment[{a, b, c, b, a}, {a, b, d, c, b, a}, 
>   SimilarityRules -> {{a_, a_} -> 1, {a_, b_} -> -1}]
> ```

So `SequenceAlignment` seems to work for lists, but not with the `SimilarityRules` option. Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: I think you have got it right, and I can't see any work-around. `SequenceAlignment` given list arguments will accept `SimilarityRules -> Automatic` which makes me suspect it is checking for `Automatic` internally in this case. I would call this a documentation bug. The documentation totally fails to discuss `SequenceAlignment` with respect to list arguments, so we are left adrift where the issue you raise is concerned. What kind similarity rules were you thinking of using for lists?

Comment: In my situation, I have two strings, `a` and `b`, where `a` was generated from `b` by removing some chunks. I want to align `a` to `b`. Therefore, my similarity rule would discount substitutions in favour of insertions, to get the best alignment. (`{{a_, a_} -> 1, {a_, ""} -> -1, {a_, b_} -> -2}`) I also use the option `GapPenalty->1`. This works for strings, but now I am trying to speed up by splitting the string into *atomic parts* (words), and putting those in lists.