# What is wrong with SimilarityRules in SequenceAlignment for lists

Tags: string-manipulation, alignment

I try to align two lists by `SequenceAlignment`. This works properly for default `SimilarityRules`

```
SequenceAlignment[
  {"Sequence","Alignment"}, {"Sequences","Alignment"}, 
  SimilarityRules -> Automatic
]
(* Out: {{{"Sequence"}, {"Sequences"}}, {"Alignment"}} *)
```

but fails for what is supposed to be the explicit form of `Automatic` according to the documentation:

```
SequenceAlignment[
  {"Sequence", "Alignment"}, {"Sequences",  "Alignment"},
  SimilarityRules -> {{a_, a_} -> 1, {a_, b_} -> -1}
]
```

I found an [old report](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97612/similarityrules-for-sequencealignment-of-two-lists) on this issue. It seems that this bug of `SequenceAlignment` has not been fixed yet.

Comment: The documentation is unclear as to what should happen when `SequenceAlignment` is given *lists* rather than strings as input. This was mentioned in the older question you linked as well.